# Run functions that exceed max AWS Lambda timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

AWS Lambda service has a timeout that can be up to 300s.

What is the common solution for running lambda functions that exceed that execution time?

We are migrating most of our stuff from standard server to Lambda and we want to migrate also scheduled applications where some of them take approx. 1 hour to execute.

Maybe Lambda is not the right solution for this, but it would be great if there was a way around it, to keep the consistency, so there is no need to have both EC2 and Lambda.

Comment: There is no common solution to substituting lambda long running services. From aws managed services, you can choose between beanstalk and ECS. Beanstalk does not need you to manage the ec2 instances, the service manages the resources needed for running your application

Comment: Lambda is not the correct solution for a task that runs up to an hour, unless you can split that task into many smaller tasks that each execute in under 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to hear that. Also the suggestion like Beanstalk and ECS, I will check that out.

Comment: This may not be relevant for this OP, however we use AWS StepFunctions for long running tasks with great success.

Answer (score -2):

Internet connection is not stable this may occur this issue .
check your internet connection speed also .